# Logback pattern change levels default colors

Tags: java, logging, logback

I need to convert a Log4j XML configuration to a Logback one. The problem that I have specifically is that I want to override the default colors of levels:

This is my Log4j code:

```xml
<Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN">%highlight{%5level}{FATAL=white, ERROR=red, WARN=blue, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}</Property>
```

And this is the Logback code that I wrote. This gives me colored levels since I added `<withJansi>true</withJansi>` on the appender, but I want to change the default colors.

```xml
<Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" value="%highlight(%5level)"/>
```

Comment: The existence of this https://github.com/shuwada/logback-custom-color suggests it is not configurable through configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this exemple works fine

Answer (score 0):

the bellow works for me using logback not log4j

Java Code

```
package com.acme.logback;

public class MyCustomHighlighting extends ForegroundCompositeConverterBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    protected String getForegroundColorCode(ILoggingEvent event) {
        Level level = event.getLevel();
        switch (level.toInt()) {
        case Level.ERROR_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.BOLD + ANSIConstants.RED_FG; // same as default color scheme
        case Level.WARN_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.RED_FG;// same as default color scheme
        case Level.INFO_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.CYAN_FG; // use CYAN instead of BLUE
        default:
            return ANSIConstants.DEFAULT_FG;
        }
    }

}
```

Logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <!-- custom coloring conversion -->
    <conversionRule conversionWord="myCustomHighlighting" converterClass="com.acme.logback.MyCustomHighlighting" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %myCustomHighlighting(%-5level) %logger{15} - %myCustomHighlighting(%msg) %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```